# Shouldn't all alternating series diverge by the diverge test?

Tags: sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence

An Alternating Series, as defined in my textbook, is of the form $\sum (-1)^n b_n$.

If we look at the nth term, the series doesn't appear to converge. If n is odd, the nth term is negative; if it's even, the nth term is positive.

My book uses this example, and after failing the Alternate Test, resorts to the diverge test. "The limit does not exist," but they don't say why, and I took the reasoning to be what I stated above. Maybe I misunderstood the text. Where did I go wrong?

[image]

Comment: The terms do not converge to zero, so the series *cannot* converge.

Comment: Ok yes, I realized my error there: even if the terms alternate positive and negative, this doesnt mean they cant converge, so long as the limit is zero. Makes sense. However, is there any reason that the book says "the limit does not exist," when it does exist as 3/4?

Comment: If I understand the book's notation, the limit of $b_n$ is $3/4$, but the limit of $a_n = (-1)^n b_n$ does not exist, since even and odd terms tend to different limits.

Comment: Yes, that's what it is. Reading your comment helped me get it, then reading Tanner's answer pretty much cemented that. Thank you both

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> If we look at the nth term, the series doesn't appear to converge. If n is odd, the nth term is negative; if it's even, the nth term is positive.

That's not true. Consider the following sequence:

$$1, -\frac12, +\frac13, -\frac14, +\frac15, -\frac16, +\frac17, \ldots$$

The terms of this sequence alternate between positive and negative, but they converge to $0$.

So what *is* the reasoning the book uses to conclude that this limit does not exist?

Speaking roughly, the reason that the limit

$$\lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{(-1)^n 3 n}{4 n - 1}$$

does not exist is that given that $n$ is very large, we do not know that the fraction is close to any particular number. For very large $n$, we know that this fraction is close to $3/4$ *or* $-3/4$, but we don't know which one. So neither $3/4$ nor $-3/4$ is the limit of this fraction.

Comment: So the limit of $b_n$ exists as 3/4, but the nth term does not because of n's unknown even/odd-ness. Ok. I was wondering why the book wouldn't simply say "the limit is 3/4 which isnt zero, therefore diverge test shows divergence." That makes more sense. And the only reason this isnt an issue when it converges to zero is because the sign isnt an issue there. Much better understanding now, thank you.

Comment: To be precise, the limit of the sequence $b_n$ is 3/4, but the sequence $a_n$ does not have a limit. You're right that when it comes to determining whether or not a sequence converges to 0, sign isn't an issue.